# Spark: calculating percentage from a non-Int field

Tags: apache-spark, sql, scala

I have a spreadsheet of banking information and one of the goals is to find out the failure rate of an advertising campaign. I think I need to get a count of the total number of entries vs. the total number of non-subscribers. The column for subscribers is a simple "yes" or "no" instead of an integer.

Of course, getting the total number of entries was easy:

```
scala> val input = sc.textFile("project_1_data.csv")
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> input.count()
res0: Long = 45211
```

Next, I filter for "no" in the subscriber column (called "y"):

```
scala> val sub = bankDF.filter($"y" === "no")
sub: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: int, job: string, marital: string, education: string, default: string, balance: int, housing: string, loan: string, contact: string, day: string, month: string, duration: int, campaign: int, pdays: string, previous: int, poutcome: string, 
y: string]

scala> sub.count()
res2: Long = 39922
```

So now I have two numbers to work with, but they're the results of two different operations. How can I work out a percentage of these two numbers in a single pass?

Also, if I may add a second question, is there maybe a reference page on how to do averages, medians, means, etc. - so I don't have to ask you guys questions every time? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT, in light of your comment and closer reading of your code**

Ok, so it looks like in your code you used the RDD api to count the
 total number of rows in the file (treating it as just a plain `RDD[String]`), whereas for counting the number of rows where `$"y" === "no"` you used the Spark-SQL API to read in the data as a `DataFrame`. I'd advise sticking to one API if you're just starting out, otherwise things will likely feel inconsistent and confusing. Since your problem lends itself nicely to operations that `DataFrame` is designed to perform, I'd recommend you stick to Spark-SQL's API.

If you want to simply calculate the ratio (as a `Double`) of rows where `$"y" === "no"`, then you could do the following:

`val ratio = bankDF.filter($"y" === "no").count().toDouble / bankDF.count()`

I still strongly recommend you read (and run for yourself) the examples in the Spark-SQL documentation. That'll give you a sense of the sorts of operations you can perform on these dataframes (e.g. means, sums, etc.).

**Original Answer**

If all you want is the proportion of rows where `y == "no"`, then simply dividing the two `Long`'s you've calculated is a really straightforward and natural way to get what you want. However, I'd highly recommend you take a look at the Spark-SQL API instead of the lower-level RDD API that you used here. For example, using Spark-SQL you can read a CSV file directly with `spark.read.csv()`, and then treat your dataset like a database table, on which you can do `groupBy()`, `filter()`, and aggregate functions like `mean()`, `sum()`, etc. The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) is quite good, so give it a look.
Spark takes some getting used to, but its really powerful once you get the hang of it. Keep at it, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you perhaps give an example of how you would express that in a command line? Unfortunately, the course I'm taking hasn't really given us these kinds of answers.